# js get query strings from styled url

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

is there a way to get the query strings from an URL that was changed with .htaccess. For example if my url is like this

```
http://mysite.com/blog.php?id=7
```

for this example, the location.search works and also the php &_GET['id'], but if i change in htaccess like this

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)$ blog.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

the url will change to

```
http://mysite.com/blog/7
```

and only the $_GET['id'] works now but not that javascript version.

Thank you, Daniel.

Answer (score 2):

You need to split the URL manually using `location.pathname.substr(1).split('/')`.

That gives you an array containing the various path segments. In your case it would contain `['blog', '7']`.

Comment: Thank you, i was 99% sure you can't really get a string like the php gives.